# ¿Cuál sería el diminutivo de lista?

Tags: gramática, diminutivos

Tomando en cuenta que uso `lista` como:

> 3. f. Enumeración, generalmente en forma de columna, de personas, cosas, cantidades, etc., que se hace con determinado propósito.

Solo me vienen dos posibles opciones a la mente: listica o listita, ¿cuál sería la correcta?

Comment: Listita es el diminutivo de lista. Ve eso https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tico

Comment: La respuesta dependerá de la región. En España, "listica" es un término válido en algunas regiones, pero suena más informal que "listita". También está la alternativa de "listilla", que es la opción que más natural me suena, pero podría confundirse con "listillo" en el sentido de "sabelotodo" o *smart ass*.

Comment: @Yay Si, es un buen punto, depende de la región, pero me parece que debería haber algo como una autoridad que defina estas reglas del lenguaje, es decir, encuentro en muchos sitios cómo agregar los sufijos, pero este caso no lo consigo.

Comment: En Colombia normalmente he escuchado siempre "Listica".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es que no hay una sola forma diminutiva, ni tampoco hay reglas precisamente estrictas para su formación.

Según la Nueva Gramática:

> **1.6b** Las restricciones léxicas relativas a la posibilidad de formar diminutivos con sustantivos son escasas, sobre todo si el diminutivo designa un objeto material.  Los diccionarios no recogen estas voces, ya que se pueden obtener mediante procedimientos combinatorios regulares. […]

Por eso, si encuentras alguna palabra en forma de diminutivo en el diccionario, es porque también ha adquirido un significado diferente del que sería simplemente «*base* pequeño<sub>/a</sub>».

Hay muchos diminutivos que se pueden emplear según §§ 9.1b, j-l de la Nueva Gramática que darían, en el caso de *lista* las siguientes formas (teniendo en cuenta también que, siendo palabra bisilábica —véase §§ 9.5c-d de la Nueva Gramática—, hay tendencia en algunas zonas de usar el infijo *-ec/ez-*): **listita, listilla, listuela, listica, listiquia, listitica, listuca, listina, listiña, listeta, listeja, listinga**, **listecita, listecilla, listezuela, listecica, listeciquia, listecitica, listezuca, listecina, listeciña, listeceta, listeceja, listecinga**.

Todas son formas perfectamente posibles y válidas, aunque algunas quizás disfrutarían de poquísimo uso, y algunas pueden ser favorecidas por uno u otro significado de la palabra.

Comment: Entiendo, también, que depende mucho de la zona. En Argentina, cualquier alternativa distinta a "listita" sonaría a foránea ("listica" suena a centroamericana, "listilla" suena a española), o incluso a peyorativa ("listuela", "listezuela"). Pero probablemente no ocurra lo mismo en otras regiones.

Comment: @mgarciasaia Precisamente. Lo importante es que el significado diminutivo sea transparente. Dado suficiente contexto, yo probablemente entendería todas estas formas, pero como palabras sueltas... buf, difícil. Peor incluso para una palabra como *puerta* que admite dos raíces (*puert-/port-*). Mi aconsejo es que los nativos usen lo que les parezca natural, porque la intuición reina en cosas así. Para los no nativos, es mejor quedar con *-ito* que tiene uso universal (aunque quizás no sabrían cuando usar infijos)

Answer (score 0):

Ninguno de los sufijos me parece realmente satisfactorio si buscamos un diminutivo cuyo uso no se restrinja a una región.

Sugeriría hablar de una *pequeña lista* de cosas / personas / cantidades, o -si queremos formar una palabra compuesta- de una *mini-lista*.