# Diminutivos de sustantivos que terminan en -to/-ta

Tags: acentuación, diminutivos

Hay formas diminutivas o afectativas que ocupan una ´c´, como ¨dar un minutico¨ o ¨pagar la cuotica¨. Supongo que sirven para evitar los supuestos malos sonidos de ¨minutito¨ y ¨cuotita¨.

Esta regla, ¿o será aceptada por la RAE, o informalidad común y corriente, o regionalismo?

Además, ¿hay algún detalle sobre la acentuación de aquellas palabras? A mi oído, suenan así como minutíco y cuótica, pero me debo estar engañando ya que esta última no respeta la regla del énfasis en la penúltima sílaba.

Comment: This question/answer may also be of interest to you http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/16423/cu%C3%A1l-ser%C3%ADa-el-diminutivo-de-lista/16424#16424

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El sufijo [-ico](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KsMjnBk) es siempre llano, como puedes ver en el diccionario. Por tanto, la pronunciación correcta sería, respectivamente, *minutíco* y *cuotíca*, con el acento siempre en la penúltima sílaba.

> **-ico, ca**
>
> 1. suf. And., Ar., Mur., Nav., Col., C. Rica, Cuba y Ven. Tiene valor diminutivo o afectivo. *Ratico, pequeñica, hermanico.* A veces, toma
>      las formas -ececico, -ecico, -cico. *Piececico, huevecico,
>      resplandorcico.*

Por otro lado, si te fijas el sufijo *-ico* tiene una fuerte componente regional (se usa en Andalucía, Aragón, Murcia y Navarra dentro de España, y en Colombia, Costa Rica, Cuba y Venezuela). Por ejemplo, yo soy de Andalucía, pero suelo usar *minutito* más que *minutico*. No creo que sea cuestión de cacofonía, sino de la costumbre del hablante.

Comment: Tienes razón que la selección va según región más que nada, con *-ito* siendo la opción más empleada panhispánicamente — quizás precisamente por haber tenido más uso en Andalucía históricamente (de eso, no tengo certeza, solo es hipótesis-intuición).  Otras opciones perfectamente válidas (y que registran por lo menos algún uso en el internet por un nativo) incluyen *minutillo, minutingo, minutín, minutiño*, y *minutuelo*.

Comment: Curioso, siempre creí que el sufijo en cuestión era más castellano (de Castilla) que de otra parte, básicamente por que mis abuelos por parte de padre son ambos de la provincia de Ávila y lo usaban relativamente a menudo.

Comment: Entonces, ¿no debe tener nada que ver con la palabra que se disminuye? Porque yo sólo lo había notado en el caso de evitar el -tito/-tita.

Comment: @AaronBrick no tiene nada que ver. Por ejemplo, _águila_ se disminuiría como _aguilita_ o _aguilica_, con tilde en la penúltima sílaba.

Comment: @AaronBrick No suele haber cacofonía, no.  Una palabra como *intento* por ejemplo fácilmente llega a ser *intentito* a pesar de tener tres /t/.  Incluso es posible encontrar un doble diminutivo como *poquitito* o *chiquitito* aunque yo personalmente empleo más *-itillo* o *-itín* cuando uso dos.

Answer (score 1):

If we look in the dictionary for -tico [here](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZibqWJB) we find that it has an accent over the dash. This means that we should place an accent over the preceding syllable. So the answer to your question about accentuation is fairly clear. This Q&A gives more information [¿Cómo se llama el símbolo ‒́?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19312/c%C3%B3mo-se-llama-el-s%C3%ADmbolo-%CC%81) about the symbol *guión con tilde*.

Comment: Note that the suffix you link is not the suffix to form diminutive variants, check my answer to see the differences.

Comment: Well @CarlosAlejo you learn something everyday. I had looked to the wrong -ico entry. I will leave my answer as a learning point unless you think it would be safer to delete it.